# Condensing javascript code for showing and hiding multiple divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can change html.

When hovering over div with id "option1", I want to show div with id "image1". When hovering over div with id "option2", I want to show div with id "image2". And so on until I reach the end (div with id "option4"). I know it can be done with css, but in some instances the order of the divs causes the css not to work.

The following javascript works, but I want to condense it so I don't have to hard code it each time I add a new div (eventually I'll have 25+ divs to do this to).

```
document.getElementById(option1).onmouseover = function() {
document.getElementById(image1).style.display = 'block';}

document.getElementById(option1).onmouseout = function() {
document.getElementById(image1).style.display = 'none';}
```

I've already tried my hand at some javascript, but it only seems to display the last image for each option I hover over.

```js
var numberOfImages = document.getElementsByClassName("product-image").length;

var i;
for (i = 1; i <= numberOfImages; i++) {
  var optionName = 'option' + i;
  var imageName = 'image' + i;

  document.getElementById(optionName).onmouseover = function() {
    document.getElementById(imageName).style.display = 'block';
  }

  document.getElementById(optionName).onmouseout = function() {
    document.getElementById(imageName).style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
.product-option-container {
  width: 66%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.product-image-container {
  width: 33%;
  height: auto;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #E1FDE2;
}

.product-option {
  width: 48%;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-bottom:15px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #FFD1D1;
}

.product-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

.product-image img {
  width: auto;
  height: 325px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-option-container">
  <div class="product-option"><span id="option1">Option 1</span></div>
  <div class="product-option"><span id="option2">Option 2</span></div><br>
  <div class="product-option"><span id="option3">Option 3</span></div>
  <div class="product-option"><span id="option4">Option 4</span></div>
</div>

<div class="product-image-container">
  <div id="image1" class="product-image"><img src="https://megavoice.com/uploads/MegaVoice-Audio-Bible-Envoy-Elite-Solar-Powered.png"></div>
  <div id="image2" class="product-image"><img src="https://megavoice.com/uploads/MegaVoice-Audio-Bible-Envoy-Echo-Solar-Powered.png"></div>
  <div id="image3" class="product-image"><img src="https://megavoice.com/uploads/MegaVoice-Audio-Bible-Envoy-Equip-Solar-Powered.png"></div>
  <div id="image4" class="product-image"><img src="https://megavoice.com/uploads/MegaVoice-Audio-Bible-Envoy-Ember-Solar-Powered.png"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is lacking a closure.

It is not really needed: Instead select all options using a CSS selector

Then either use a data-attribute or as here, replace the id with the image id

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".product-option>span").forEach(function(opt) {
  opt.onmouseover = function() {
    document.getElementById("image"+this.id.replace("option","")).style.display = 'block';
  }

  opt.onmouseout = function() {
    document.getElementById("image"+this.id.replace("option","")).style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```css
.product-option-container {
  width: 66%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.product-image-container {
  width: 33%;
  height: auto;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #E1FDE2;
}

.product-option {
  width: 48%;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-bottom:15px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #FFD1D1;
}

.product-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

.product-image img {
  width: auto;
  height: 325px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-option-container">
  <div class="product-option"><span id="option1">Option 1</span></div>
  <div class="product-option"><span id="option2">Option 2</span></div><br>
  <div class="product-option"><span id="option3">Option 3</span></div>
  <div class="product-option"><span id="option4">Option 4</span></div>
</div>

<div class="product-image-container">
  <div id="image1" class="product-image"><img src="https://megavoice.com/uploads/MegaVoice-Audio-Bible-Envoy-Elite-Solar-Powered.png"></div>
  <div id="image2" class="product-image"><img src="https://megavoice.com/uploads/MegaVoice-Audio-Bible-Envoy-Echo-Solar-Powered.png"></div>
  <div id="image3" class="product-image"><img src="https://megavoice.com/uploads/MegaVoice-Audio-Bible-Envoy-Equip-Solar-Powered.png"></div>
  <div id="image4" class="product-image"><img src="https://megavoice.com/uploads/MegaVoice-Audio-Bible-Envoy-Ember-Solar-Powered.png"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This (along with each of the other answers) solved my problem! Thanks for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code, as written, is that after the last iteration of the loop, `optionName` and `imageName` are the values for the last iteration, so when you do

```
document.getElementById(imageName)
```

for example, `imageName` is the value of the last iteration.  If you wrap that part in a closure:

```
var optionName = 'option' + i;
var imageName = 'image' + i;
(function (imageName, optionName) {
   //your code
})(imageName, optionName);
```

Then the values won't change inside of the closure, so it will all work as expected:

```js
var numberOfImages = document.getElementsByClassName("product-image").length;

var i;
for (i = 1; i <= numberOfImages; i++) {
  var optionName = 'option' + i;
  var imageName = 'image' + i;
  (function(optionName, imageName) {
    document.getElementById(optionName).onmouseover = function() {
      document.getElementById(imageName).style.display = 'block';
    }

    document.getElementById(optionName).onmouseout = function() {
      document.getElementById(imageName).style.display = 'none';
    }
  })(optionName, imageName);
}
```

```css
.product-option-container {
  width: 66%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.product-image-container {
  width: 33%;
  height: auto;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #E1FDE2;
}

.product-option {
  width: 48%;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-bottom:15px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #FFD1D1;
}

.product-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

.product-image img {
  width: auto;
  height: 325px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-option-container">
  <div class="product-option"><span id="option1">Option 1</span></div>
  <div class="product-option"><span id="option2">Option 2</span></div><br>
  <div class="product-option"><span id="option3">Option 3</span></div>
  <div class="product-option"><span id="option4">Option 4</span></div>
</div>

<div class="product-image-container">
  <div id="image1" class="product-image"><img src="https://megavoice.com/uploads/MegaVoice-Audio-Bible-Envoy-Elite-Solar-Powered.png"></div>
  <div id="image2" class="product-image"><img src="https://megavoice.com/uploads/MegaVoice-Audio-Bible-Envoy-Echo-Solar-Powered.png"></div>
  <div id="image3" class="product-image"><img src="https://megavoice.com/uploads/MegaVoice-Audio-Bible-Envoy-Equip-Solar-Powered.png"></div>
  <div id="image4" class="product-image"><img src="https://megavoice.com/uploads/MegaVoice-Audio-Bible-Envoy-Ember-Solar-Powered.png"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm very new to javascript and your explanation helped a lot!

Comment: What would I need to do to the code to make div with id "image1" visible if Option 1 was a checked checkbox (with name="checkbox-600[]")?

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".product-option span").forEach(function(v, i) {
    v.onmouseover = function() {
        document.getElementById("image" + (i + 1)).style.display = 'block';
    }
    v.onmouseout = function() {
        document.getElementById("image" + (i + 1)).style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

```css
.product-option-container {
  width: 66%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.product-image-container {
  width: 33%;
  height: auto;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #E1FDE2;
}

.product-option {
  width: 48%;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-bottom:15px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #FFD1D1;
}

.product-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

.product-image img {
  width: auto;
  height: 325px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-option-container">
  <div class="product-option"><span id="option1">Option 1</span></div>
  <div class="product-option"><span id="option2">Option 2</span></div><br>
  <div class="product-option"><span id="option3">Option 3</span></div>
  <div class="product-option"><span id="option4">Option 4</span></div>
</div>

<div class="product-image-container">
  <div id="image1" class="product-image"><img src="https://megavoice.com/uploads/MegaVoice-Audio-Bible-Envoy-Elite-Solar-Powered.png"></div>
  <div id="image2" class="product-image"><img src="https://megavoice.com/uploads/MegaVoice-Audio-Bible-Envoy-Echo-Solar-Powered.png"></div>
  <div id="image3" class="product-image"><img src="https://megavoice.com/uploads/MegaVoice-Audio-Bible-Envoy-Equip-Solar-Powered.png"></div>
  <div id="image4" class="product-image"><img src="https://megavoice.com/uploads/MegaVoice-Audio-Bible-Envoy-Ember-Solar-Powered.png"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is assuming the images are in the order of the options

Answer (score 0):

I like @mplungjan's answer, but you were right, the logic behind you code made sense. The issue was in how JS deals with `var` declarations. To put it simply, declaring `var`s in a loop can lead to non-intuitive outcomes and, if you have the option, you should use `let` instead. I've replaced `var` with `let` in your code and it seems to work.

```js
var numberOfImages = document.getElementsByClassName("product-image").length;

var i;
for (i = 1; i <= numberOfImages; i++) {
  let optionName = 'option' + i;
  let imageName = 'image' + i;

  document.getElementById(optionName).onmouseover = function() {
    document.getElementById(imageName).style.display = 'block';
  }

  document.getElementById(optionName).onmouseout = function() {
    document.getElementById(imageName).style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
.product-option-container {
  width: 66%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.product-image-container {
  width: 33%;
  height: auto;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #E1FDE2;
}

.product-option {
  width: 48%;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-bottom:15px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #FFD1D1;
}

.product-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

.product-image img {
  width: auto;
  height: 325px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-option-container">
  <div class="product-option"><span id="option1">Option 1</span></div>
  <div class="product-option"><span id="option2">Option 2</span></div><br>
  <div class="product-option"><span id="option3">Option 3</span></div>
  <div class="product-option"><span id="option4">Option 4</span></div>
</div>

<div class="product-image-container">
  <div id="image1" class="product-image"><img src="https://megavoice.com/uploads/MegaVoice-Audio-Bible-Envoy-Elite-Solar-Powered.png"></div>
  <div id="image2" class="product-image"><img src="https://megavoice.com/uploads/MegaVoice-Audio-Bible-Envoy-Echo-Solar-Powered.png"></div>
  <div id="image3" class="product-image"><img src="https://megavoice.com/uploads/MegaVoice-Audio-Bible-Envoy-Equip-Solar-Powered.png"></div>
  <div id="image4" class="product-image"><img src="https://megavoice.com/uploads/MegaVoice-Audio-Bible-Envoy-Ember-Solar-Powered.png"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer works! I like keeping my code the way it is (but changing "var" to "let") as it means I don't have to also keep track of the span element. However, I think the code is a little simpler with the one marked as the right answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. `let` is a relatively recent addition to JavaScript and won't work in, for instance, Internet Explorer. @dave's answer is the more traditional way to deal with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using ES6 and can't use `let` to declare your variables then you will need to immediately invoke a function (via a closure) which will return a function. The function returned from the IIFE will be what you assign as your  `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` event handlers.

This issue is a common pitfall for new JavaScript developers still learning how scoping works in JavaScript.

Below is an example:

```js
var numberOfImages = document.getElementsByClassName("product-image").length;

for (i = 1; i <= numberOfImages; i++) {
  var optionName = 'option' + i;

  document.getElementById(optionName).onmouseover = (function() {
    var imageName = 'image' + i;
    return function() {
      document.getElementById(imageName).style.display = 'block';
    }
  })();

  document.getElementById(optionName).onmouseout = (function() {
    var imageName = 'image' + i;
    return function() {
      document.getElementById(imageName).style.display = 'none';
    }
  })();
}
```

```css
.product-option-container {
  width: 66%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.product-image-container {
  width: 33%;
  height: auto;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #E1FDE2;
}

.product-option {
  width: 48%;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #FFD1D1;
}

.product-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

.product-image img {
  width: auto;
  height: 325px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-option-container">
  <div class="product-option"><span id="option1">Option 1</span></div>
  <div class="product-option"><span id="option2">Option 2</span></div><br>
  <div class="product-option"><span id="option3">Option 3</span></div>
  <div class="product-option"><span id="option4">Option 4</span></div>
</div>

<div class="product-image-container">
  <div id="image1" class="product-image"><img src="https://megavoice.com/uploads/MegaVoice-Audio-Bible-Envoy-Elite-Solar-Powered.png"></div>
  <div id="image2" class="product-image"><img src="https://megavoice.com/uploads/MegaVoice-Audio-Bible-Envoy-Echo-Solar-Powered.png"></div>
  <div id="image3" class="product-image"><img src="https://megavoice.com/uploads/MegaVoice-Audio-Bible-Envoy-Equip-Solar-Powered.png"></div>
  <div id="image4" class="product-image"><img src="https://megavoice.com/uploads/MegaVoice-Audio-Bible-Envoy-Ember-Solar-Powered.png"></div>
</div>
```

Here's a page that explains a bit about closures in JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures